# Good source for learning to insert figures according to one's choice

Tags: learning

I am new to LaTeX. Can someone please suggest me a good source for understanding how figure insertion in latex works and for learning how to insert figures according to one's choice in LaTeX.

Comment: This posting on this site assumes some existing basic knowledge, but it is a detailed presentation by the director of the LaTeX3 working group: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Comment: Does one of the provided answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the `memoir` class (`> texdoc memoir`) includes **10.4 Where LaTeX puts floats** which describes many aspects of the positioning of floats (`figure`, `table`, etc).

I have a feeling that somewhere on the SE site is a more comprehensive answer that does not necessitate buying a book, but *The Latex Graphics Companion* provides much information on possibly some of your future questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think that *The LaTeX Graphics Companion*, by Michael Goosens, Frank Mittelbach, Sebastian Rahtz, Denis Roegel, and Herbert Voß, has all you might want and still more.